# How to delay a button display to 2s in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

I have a button component which I am using in several places. But I want to show that button after 2s on a specific page.
How can I achieve this in Vuejs/CSS?

```js
<OHButton
        v-show="this.campIndex < 2 && modalShow"
        :title="'next'"
        :onClick="goToSlides"
      >
</OHButton>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a data property called `delayShow` and in `created` hook use `setTimeout` function to set it to `true`:

```
data(){
  return{
   delayShow:false,
 ...   

 }
},
created(){
 setTimeout(()=>{
  this.delayShow=true;
},2000)
}
```

in template :

```
<OHButton
        v-show="delayShow && modalShow"
        :title="'next'"
        @click="goToSlides"
      >
</OHButton>
```